# Socket And Client response

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

now all i need is the server still be connected after i complete one tast,
like if i write the str command "time" i get the time and can still connect with the server i try to add some "if" statement and make while for the "choice" input, but i still cannot make this work i always get blank response and disconnected from the server, thank you for help and sorry about the English.

i need some help with this code:

```
import socket
import time

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
server.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server.accept()
client_rq = client_socket.recv(1024)
b = time.ctime()


if client_rq == "name":
    client_socket.send('the server name is london project')

if client_rq == "help":
    client_socket.send('for help with this server connect @gmail.com')

if client_rq == "time":
    client_socket.send(b)

server.close()
```

and this is the client:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket()
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))

x = raw_input("choice: ")
client.send(x)
data = client.recv(1024)
print data

client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop in the server:

```
import socket
import time

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
server.listen(1)
while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server.accept()
    client_rq = client_socket.recv(1024)
    b = time.ctime()

    if client_rq == "name":
        client_socket.send('the server name is london project')

    if client_rq == "help":
        client_socket.send('for help with this server connect @gmail.com')

    if client_rq == "time":
        client_socket.send(b)

    if client_rq == "quit":
        break # from the loop

server.close()
```

Send "quit" from the client to break the loop and exit the server.

Comment: thank you its kind of work, but im still cannot complete this before i make while on client, and i cannot create tuple of "command" like ['name', 'time', 'exit'] that everything like 'bla bla' make the server dosent response and the raw input dont send the string i try if client_rq is not [a b c d]

Comment: client_rq is not [a, b, c, d]. Without commas all strings concatenated into one.